# Combine multiple JSON dictionary List into single dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing, jsonparser

i have the following set of lines in out.json file

```
{"rl": {"entries": [{"value": {"query": "4c20a3718c3cfcc2cd418a25a020e608"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "af6c05f057c80944a88c014c1c081c83e2e9"}, "status": "KNOWN"}]}}
{"rl": {"entries": [{"value": {"query": "fb0e8c7d856e7e5c99c339d593f26aa9b"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "49d9890de7e394f3549510fdeafa888"}, "status": "KNOWN"}]}}
{"rl": {"entries": [{"value": {"query": "bf2f9b6c00432a54e229c75e2b13bb"}, "status": "SUSPICIOUS"}, {"value": {"query": "b7cb4b620854f2b0d5dfe86ffd9ab"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "9b4e2465b2da99097899662eec2b"}, "status": "KNOWN"}]}}
```

Now, i want to merge all the dictionary list into one list in single file like below set of code :

```
{"rl": {"entries": [{"value": {"query": "fb0e8c7d856e7e5c99c339d593f26aa9b"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "bf2f9b6c00432a54e229c75e2b13bb"}, "status": "SUSPICIOUS"}, {"value": {"query": "9b4e2465b2da99097899662eec2b"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "4c20a3718c3cfcc2cd418a25a020e608"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "b7cb4b620854f2b0d5dfe86ffd9ab"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "49d9890de7e394f3549510fdeafa888"}, "status": "KNOWN"}, {"value": {"query": "af6c05f057c80944a88c014c1c081c83e2e9"}, "status": "KNOWN"}]}}
```

Need to parse the out.json ,which contains same structure of dictionary list, need output into single set of list.

Comment: The concept is straightforward as you just have to load each line, parse the JSON and keep concatenating the array. Please post the code you have tried, so others can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(file_path) as f:
    dict_ls  = [literal_eval(i) for i in f.readlines()]
combine_list = []
res_dict = {}
for i in dict_ls:
    for k, v in i.items():
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            res_dict[k] = {list(v.keys())[0]: combine_list}
            dict_ls.append(v)
        else:
            combine_list.extend(v)
print(res_dict)
```

This will output

```
{'rl': {'entries': [{'value': {'query': '4c20a3718c3cfcc2cd418a25a020e608'}, 'status': 'KNOWN'}, {'value': {'query': 'af6c05f057c80944a88c014c1c081c83e2e9'}, 'status': 'KNOWN'}, {'value': {'query': 'fb0e8c7d856e7e5c99c339d593f26aa9b'}, 'status': 'KNOWN'}, {'value': {'query': '49d9890de7e394f3549510fdeafa888'}, 'status': 'KNOWN'}, {'value': {'query': 'bf2f9b6c00432a54e229c75e2b13bb'}, 'status': 'SUSPICIOUS'}, {'value': {'query': 'b7cb4b620854f2b0d5dfe86ffd9ab'}, 'status': 'KNOWN'}, {'value': {'query': '9b4e2465b2da99097899662eec2b'}, 'status': 'KNOWN'}]}}
```

First needed to convert each line in the file to a dictionary by the `literal_eval` method. 
Then this code will run over each dictionary in the `dict_ls` list and will get all the list values into the combined list and will create in `res_dict` all the keys that found in each dictionary keys.

Comment: @ Leo Arad, that's working.But when i try to pass in from file, its shows error, i tried like 
        with open ('out.json') as readfile :
           dict_ls = readfile.read()

Comment: I've edited the code for reading from a file just change the file_path to your current file path. The main differences are to convert each dictionary string to a dictionary by the `literal_eval` method.

Comment: i have more nested dictionary in that same structure,that is not working with your code,is there any way , i can simply get the list under '"rl": {"entries":' and append it to final list '"rl": {"entries":'

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the other data but it looks like you can do something inside the if not isinstance(v, list):

Comment: it's not even loading with  "[literal_eval(i) for i in f.readlines()]", its not accepting,shows error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216559/discussion-between-pavithran-g-and-leo-arad).